# All ng-clicks inside modal stop working after awhile

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a peculiar problem that I'm having a tough time making sense of. I have a modal that opens when a user wants to attach media to a post on my site. The modal itself is way too complex to reproduce on a Fiddle, but suffice it to say, it's basically a div with several nested divs, each of which represents a tab in the modal with it's own controller.

When I load the page, everything works as expected. After a few clicks (sometimes as many as 100+, all the ng-click events within the modal cease to work. I can still open/close the modal, but nothing within it works. There are no console errors or anything. I haven't been able to identify a pattern to the problem either. Sometimes the ng-clicks stop working after just a dozen clicks, other times it takes 100+ clicks to break it.

Some of the ng-clicks are nested within ng-repeat elements, while other sare not nested within anything. What's strange is that all the ng-clicks stop working, regardless of whether they are within a repeater or regardless of which controller they fall under. When I close the modal, other ng-clicks on the page still work.

**Update**

I made some tweaks to my code. I still have the problem, but I've been able to narrow down a pattern to it now. It seems to be triggered after I open/close the modal 3 times. Each time I open the modal, I switch tabs. Then on the third time I open the modal, everything is frozen. I'm pretty sure the problem lies with my tabs. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ng-class="{'active-sub': view === 'photos'}">
        <a href="#" ng-click="setView('photos');">Photos</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{'active-sub': view === 'videos'}">
        <a href="#" ng-click="setView('videos');">Videos</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{'active-sub': view === 'surveys'}">
        <a href="#" ng-click="setView('surveys');">Mini-Posts</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then in my controller:

```
$scope.view = 'photos';
$scope.setView = function(view) {
    $scope.view = view;
};
```

If I insert a `console.log()` into that function, I can see the view name changes every time until the modal freezes, at which point clicking a tab does nothing.

I've further narrowed down the problem. The freeze only occurs when you close the modal without selecting an attachment. That is done by click outside the modal or on the close button, which triggers the modals's close function. Here is the modal source code:

```
app.service('modal', [function() {
    var modal = this;
    modal.settings = {};
    modal.overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
    modal.modal = $('<div id="modal"></div>');
    modal.content = $('<div id="content"></div>');
    modal.closeBtn = $('<div id="close"><i class="fa fa-times"></div>');

    modal.modal.hide();
    modal.overlay.hide();
    modal.modal.append(modal.content, modal.closeBtn);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').append(modal.overlay, modal.modal);
    });

    modal.open = function (settings) {
        modal.settings = settings;
        var content = modal.settings.content;

        modal.content.empty().append(content);
        if(modal.settings.class) modal.modal.addClass(modal.settings.class);
        if(modal.settings.height) modal.modal.css({ height: settings.height });
        if(modal.settings.width) modal.modal.css({ width: settings.width });
        if(modal.settings.content_height) modal.modal.css({ height: settings.content_height });
        if(modal.settings.content_width) modal.modal.css({ width: settings.content_width });
        if(modal.settings.fitToWindow) {
            modal.settings.width = $(window).width() - 160;
            modal.settings.height = $(window).height() - 160;
        };
        center(modal.settings.top);

        $(window).bind('resize.modal', center);
        modal.modal.show();
        modal.overlay.show();

        $(modal.closeBtn).add(modal.overlay).on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            modal.close();
        });
        $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                modal.close();
                $(document).unbind('keyup');
            }
        })
    };

    modal.close = function() {
        var elem = modal.settings.elem;
        var content = modal.settings.content;

        elem.empty().append(content);

        modal.modal.hide();
        modal.overlay.hide();
        modal.content.empty();
        $(window).unbind('resize.modal');
    };

    function center(top) {
        if(!top || !isInt(top)) top = 130;
        var mLeft = -1 * modal.modal.width() / 2;
        modal.modal.css({
            top: top + 'px',
            left: '50%',
            marginLeft: mLeft
        });
        function isInt(n) {
           return n % 1 === 0;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Please show some code, so I can try to help.

Comment: Just updated my post. I was able to isolate the problem to the tabs in the modal.

Comment: what would be wrong with ui-bootstrap modal ? https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: I needed something a little but more customized for my needs.

Comment: I Am trying to create a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/V4KOHQWWPkirHxZCwmdc?p=preview

Comment: sounds I need the css classes, you define, would you provide it?